# How to ensure table cells in fixed head are in same width with cells in scrollable body?

Tags: html, css, html-table

My HTML for the table is like this **`(in tbody, data is loaded from an ajax call)`**:

```
<table class="table table-sm table-bordered text-center">
    <thead class="text-center text-white">
        <tr>
            <td>Country</td>
            <td>Crop</td>
            <td>Trials</td>
            <td>Nurseries</td>
            <td>Unspecified</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="country-crop-trials"></tbody>
</table>
```

And my CSS is like this

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: white;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: black;
}

thead{
    display: block;
    background-color: #08381f;
    display: table;
    width: calc(100% - 5px);
}

tbody {
    display: block;
    max-height: 360px;
    width: calc(100% - 5px);
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

And my table displays like this:
[image]

I tried changing some style properties but cannot get it right. Someone please help me so that the columns in table head align with columns in table body

Comment: Remove the display prop to the thead and the tbody. Also you should use th instead of td in the thead.

Comment: use `.table {table-layout: fixed; width: 100%;}`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `table-layout: fixed` to make sure the columns stretch with the table header. However, if you use `position: fixed` on table header you will end up in more layout issues.

If you still need to proceed with `<table>` tag itself, consider playing with `display: flex` on `tr` and use `position: sticky`.

Check the demo below.

```css
* {
  margin: 0
}

.table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.table tr {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.table td {
  width: 20%;
  padding: 5px;
}

thead tr {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-sm table-bordered text-center">
  <thead class="text-center text-white">
    <tr>
      <td>Country</td>
      <td>Crop</td>
      <td>Trials</td>
      <td>Nurseries</td>
      <td>Unspecified</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="country-crop-trials">
    <tr>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This snippet does not work